# How to get a Unique ID to Div Boxes generated from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

this is the code i have:

```
        $output .= '<div class="col-md-3"><div class="single-post">';
        if ($row["fahrzeugBild"] !== "") {
          $output .= '<img src="img/cars/'.$row["fahrzeugBild"].'.jpg" alt="">';
        }
```

Here is the javascript

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("tuning");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

I am using it in a PHP/sql array, and so the divs needed to show/hide are generated from a database. But when i use this script, it works only for the first div in the array.... So(i think) i basically need to be able to generate a unique id for each div automatically. but here is the problem, i don't know how and yes my code looks like a mess but i'm still learning php so forgive me for that.
Any help would be amazing.

Comment: Try with something like `$output .= '<p><button onclick="myFunction()">Show/Hide</button><div id="tuning'.$row['id'].'" style="display:none;">Tuning Details</p>';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

PHP

```
$customId = random_int(10000, 99999);
        $output .= '<p><button onclick="myFunction('.$customId.')">Show/Hide</button><div id="tuning'.$customId.'" style="display:none;">Tuning Details</p>';
```

and in your Javascript:

```
function myFunction(customId) {
  var x = document.getElementById("tuning"+customId);
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**:
Ideally, instead, you would assign a unique ID instead of a random number, for example if in your database each item has an autoincremental ID, you could use that autoincremental ID, preferably, and assign it to each `div`

Comment: Thanks for the solution!
How is it possible now to get the css on all custom IDs? 
#tuning div {
     padding-left:5px;
     float:left;
}
 #tuning img {
     width:12px;
     height:12px;
}

Comment: Try with `div[id^="tuning"] { padding-left:5px; float:left; } #tuning img { width:12px; height:12px; }` :)

Comment: This isn't working. Give me still a horrible result. I think this can't be found #tuning img { 
    width:12px; 
    height:12px; 
}
Becaus image is still big but the divs are floating left

Comment: Try with: `div[id^="tuning"] div { padding-left:5px; float:left; } ` and `div[id^="tuning"] img { width:12px; height:12px; }`

Comment: Still not working, this is how it should looks like : https://prnt.sc/s9mzqo
and how it looks now with the same CSS code : https://prnt.sc/s9n07d
The image btw is 15x15

Comment: In your PHP code replace this: `$output .='<div><img src="img/x_icon.png">&nbsp;Kein Tuning moeglich!</div>';` with this `$output .='<div><img class="xicon" src="img/x_icon.png">&nbsp;Kein Tuning moeglich!</div>';` and add this to your CSS: `img.xicon { width:12px; height:12px; }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212963/discussion-between-nestor-and-mkeey).